# What is the result of a yield expression in Python?

Tags: python, generator, yield

I know that yield turns a function into a generator, but what is the return value of the yield expression itself?  For example:

```
def whizbang(): 
    for i in range(10): 
        x = yield i
```

What is the value of variable `x` as this function executes?

I've read the Python documentation: http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-yield_stmt and there seems to be no mention of the value of the yield expression itself.

Comment: Of course, the experimental result is that it always returns "None" but I just want to confirm this.

Comment: Your link points to the documentation of `yield` as a statement, but you are using a [`yield` expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) in the example code.

Comment: FWIW, `yield` expressions were introduced in 2.5 following the approval of [PEP 342](https://peps.python.org/pep-0342/)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can also `send` values to generators. If no value is sent then `x` is `None`, otherwise `x` takes on the sent value. Here is some info: http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-342-new-generator-features

```
>>> def whizbang():
        for i in range(10):
            x = yield i
            print 'got sent:', x


>>> i = whizbang()
>>> next(i)
0
>>> next(i)
got sent: None
1
>>> i.send("hi")
got sent: hi
2
```

Comment: Wow.  Why this isn't mentioned in the documentation for yield is totally beyond me.  Where do I submit doc bugs?

Comment: @slacy Not sure about both of those.

Comment: @slacy, huh? It _is_ mentioned in the documentation for [yield](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator.send).

Comment: @slacy, though I admit after looking around, it's a bit hard to find from the table of contents.

Comment: How would you use something like this?

Comment: Can you link to it?  I don't see it anywhere in the current docs.  I did find it here: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/yieldexpr.html but not http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-yield_stmt or http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/reference/index.html

Comment: How is this a doc bug? At http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions the second paragraph ends with `The value of the yield expression after resuming depends on the method which resumed the execution.` This is followed by the method definitions with `next()` saying `When a generator function is resumed with a next() method, the current yield expression always evaluates to None.` The very next listed method is `send()`: `The value argument becomes the result of the current yield expression.` It's all there.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor The docs for the yield statement and yield expression are poorly cut & pasted and modified versions of each other. There's no mention at all in the yield statement docs about yield expressions (and their different behavior).  I think this would be lost to many programmers, even advanced ones, like myself.

Comment: I'm not surprising that docs about *statements* don't talk about *expressions*, they're two separate things. As you were looking for the result of a *yield expression*, then reading up on statements was a waste of time, something I would expect an "advanced" programmer to be aware of. Those three lines are each very clear, tell you exactly what you wanted to know (they *explicitly* state what the expression evaluates to!) and were obviously placed in the documentation.

Comment: and interestingly you have to call `next()` at least once before `send()` or you get `TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started generator`