# Python: yield and yield assignment

Tags: python, yield, assignment-operator

How does this code, involving assignment and the yield operator, work?  The results are rather confounding.

```
def test1(x): 
    for i in x:
        _ = yield i 
        yield _
def test2(x): 
    for i in x:
        _ = yield i 

r1 = test1([1,2,3])
r2 = test2([1,2,3])
print list(r1)
print list(r2)
```

Output:

```
[1, None, 2, None, 3, None] 
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why, but the one question most likely to appear in the "Related" list in any Python question is [the `yield` question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python), even if the question in question has nothing to do with `yield`. This time, however, it is indeed related.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: related questions are due to someone linking from one question to the other. So presumably there are a lot of comments pointing to that question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The assignment syntax ("yield expression") allows you to treat the generator as a rudimentary coroutine.

First proposed in [PEP 342](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) and documented here: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions

The client code that is working with the generator can communicate data back into the generator using its `send()` method.  That data is accessible via the assignment syntax.

`send()` will also iterate - so it actually includes a `next()` call.

Using your example, this is what it would be like to use the couroutine functionality:

```
>>> def test1(x):
...     for i in x:
...         _ = yield i
...         yield _
...
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> gen_instance = test1(l)

>>> #First send has to be a None
>>> print gen_instance.send(None)
1
>>> print gen_instance.send("A")
A
>>> print gen_instance.send("B")
2
>>> print gen_instance.send("C")
C
>>> print gen_instance.send("D")
3
>>> print gen_instance.send("E")
E
>>> print gen_instance.send("F")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Note that some of the sends are lost because of the second `yield` in each loop iteration that doesn't capture the sent data.

**EDIT:** 
Forgot to explain the `None`s yielded in your example.

From https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator.next:

> When a generator function is resumed with a next() method, the current
>   yield expression always evaluates to None.

`next()` is used when using the iteration syntax.

Answer (score 12):

```
_ = yield i 
yield _
```

First it `yield`s the value referenced by `i`, e.g. `1`. Then it yields the value returned by the `yield` operation, which is `None`. It does this on each iteration of the loop.

```
for i in x:
    _ = yield i
```

This simply `yield`s the value referenced by `i`, e.g. `1`, then proceeds to the next iteration of the loop, producing `2`, then `3`.

Unlike `return`, the `yield` keyword can be used in an expression:

```
x = return 0 # SyntaxError
x = yield 0 # perfectly fine
```

Now, when the interpreter sees a `yield`, it will generate the indicated value. However, when it does so, that operation returns the value `None`, just like `mylist.append(0)` or `print('hello')` will `return` the value `None`. When you assign that result to a reference like `_`, you're saving that `None`.

So, in the first snippet, you're yielding an object, then you save the "result" of that `yield` operation, which is `None`, and then you `yield` that `None`. In the second snippet, you yield an object, then you save the "result" of that `yield` operation, but you *never `yield` that result*, so `None` does not appear in the output.

Note that `yield` won't always return `None` - this is just what you sent to the generator with `send()`. Since that was nothing in this case, you get `None`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695456/what-is-the-result-of-a-yield-expression-in-python) for more on `send()`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman - Sure, I'll add some more detailed explanation.

Comment: @JohnKugelman - Information added. Please let me know if any of the wording is unclear or misleading.

Comment: The clearest explanation for me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on TigerhawkT3's answer, the reason that the yield operation is returning `None` in your code is because `list(r1)` isn't sending anything *into* the generator. Try this:

```
def test1(x):
    for i in x:
        _ = yield i
        yield _


r1 = test1([1, 2, 3])

for x in r1:
    print('   x', x)
    print('send', r1.send('hello!'))
```

Output:

```
   x 1
send hello!
   x 2
send hello!
   x 3
send hello!
```

Here's a somewhat manufactured example where sending values into a generator could be useful:

```
def changeable_count(start=0):
    current = start
    while True:
        changed_current = yield current
        if changed_current:
            current = changed_current
        else:
            current += 1

counter = changeable_count(10)

for x in range(20):
    print(next(counter), end=' ')

print()
print()

print('Sending 51, printing return value:', counter.send(51))
print()

for x in range(20):
    print(next(counter), end=' ')

print()
print()

print('Sending 42, NOT printing return value')
print()

counter.send(42)

for x in range(20):
    print(next(counter), end=' ')

print()
```

Output:

```
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 

Sending 51, printing return value: 51

52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 

Sending 42, NOT printing return value

43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62
```