# Python create an iterator/generator with feedback

Tags: python, generator

Is it possible to create a iterator/generator which will decide on the next value based on some **result** on the previous iteration?

i.e.

```
y = None
for x in some_iterator(ll, y):
  y = some_calculation_on(x)
```

I would like the logic of choosing the next `x` to depend on the calculation result allowing different logic for different results, much like in a search problem.

I also want to keep the how to choose the next `x` and the calculation on `x` as separate as possible.

Comment: I'm not fully clear on what your question is, but I think the `yield` keyword might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do

Comment: Can you show more code to illustrate your problem?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128412/python-yield-and-yield-assignment)

Comment: @andrew, might be tricky to understand at first but I think this is a nice way to do what OP wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you that you can send to a generator using [`generator.send`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send)? So yes, you can have a generator to change its behaviour based on feedback from the outside world. From the doc:

> `generator`.**send**(*value*)
>
> Resumes the execution and “sends” a value into the generator function.
>   The value argument becomes the result of the current yield expression.
>   The `send()` method returns the next value yielded by the generator
>   [...]

### Example

Here is a counter that will increment only if told to do so.

```
def conditionalCounter(start=0):
    while True:
        should_increment = yield start
        if should_increment:
            start += 1
```

#### Usage

Since iteration with a for-loop does not allow to use `generator.send`, you have to use a  while-loop.

```
import random

def some_calculation_on(value):
    return random.choice([True, False])

g = conditionalCounter()

last_value = next(g)

while last_value < 5:
    last_value = g.send(some_calculation_on(last_value))
    print(last_value)
```

#### Output

```
0
0
1
2
3
3
4
4
5
```

### Make it work in a for-loop

You can make the above work in a for-loop by crafting a `YieldReceive` class.

```
class YieldReceive:
    stop_iteration = object()

    def __init__(self, gen):
        self.gen = gen
        self.next = next(gen, self.stop_iteration)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.next is self.stop_iteration:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            return self.next

    def send(self, value):
        try:
            self.next = self.gen.send(value)
        except StopIteration:
            self.next = self.stop_iteration
```

#### Usage

```
it = YieldReceive(...)
for x in it:
    # Do stuff
    it.send(some_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's *possible* but confusing. If you want to keep the *sequence* of `x` values and the calculations on `x` separate, you should do this explicitly by not involving `x` with an iterator.

```
def next_value(x):
    """Custom iterator"""
    # Bunch of code defining a new x
    yield new_x


x = None
while True:
    x = next_value(x)
    x = some_calculation_on(x)
    # Break when you're done
    if finished and done:
        break
```

If you want the loop to execute exactly `i` times, then use a `for` loop:

```
for step in range(i):
    x = next_value(x)
    x = some_calculation_on(x)
    # No break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def conditional_iterator(y):
    # stuff to create new values
    yield x if (expression involving y) else another_x

for x in conditional_iterator(y):
    y = some_computation(x)
```