# Python from generator to list

Tags: python, list, generator, yield

I've seen some examples where we can transfer `generator` into `list` as below.

First example:

```
print [2 * n for n in range(5)]
# same as the list comprehension above
print list(2 * n for n in range(5))
```

Second example:

```
def double(L):
    for x in L:
        yield x*2

# eggs will be a generator
eggs = double([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
# the above is equivalent to ("generator comprehension"?)
eggs = (x*2 for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
# need to do this if you need a list
eggs = list(double([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
print eggs
# the above is equivalent to (list comprehension)
eggs = [x*2 for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
print eggs
```

My question is, can all `generators` be transferred into `list`?(I failed at below example):

```
def get_primes(number):
    while True:
        if is_prime(number):
            number = yield number
        number += 1

def is_prime(number):
    if number > 1:
        if number == 2:
            return True
        if number % 2 == 0:
            return False
        for current in range(3, int(math.sqrt(number) + 1), 2):
            if number % current == 0:
                return False
        return True
    return False

generator = get_primes(5)
print list(generator)
```

Output:`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'int'`

The problem is here:`number = yield number` for some reason. Some explanation on this are appreciated.

Comment: What? `number = yield number`? `yield` doesn't return anything.

Comment: I'll edit it, I use it to test send() before.

Comment: Don't edit it, because that line is why you're getting that TypeError.

Comment: `yield` actually can [return a value in a way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695456/what-is-the-result-of-a-yield-expression-in-python).

Comment: @ZhaoWu Looks like you are trying to form an infinite generator. Making a list out of this will cause `MemoryError` (system running out of memory)

Comment: @user2357112: true...Thanks...And do you mind a brief explanation?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Yes, however OP said he knows that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your generator is broken:

```
number = yield number
```

This should just be `yield number`. Assigning the value of a `yield` expression to a variable is only useful when you expect the caller to `send` values into the generator. When you just iterate over a generator normally, all its yield expressions evaluate to `None`. This line assigns `None` to `number`, and then `number += 1` TypeErrors because you're trying to add an integer to `None`.

If you had tried to iterate over this generator with a `for` loop, you would have gotten the same error.

---

That said, not all generators can be converted to a list, and your code, either fixed or unfixed, is an example of why: a generator might throw an exception or yield values forever. The `list` constructor is roughly equivalent to

```
def list(arg):
    l = []
    for item in arg:
        l.append(arg)
    return l
```

If the generator throws an exception, the exception propagates out of the `list` constructor and terminates the loop. If the generator yields forever, the loop goes forever, or at least until you run out of memory or patience. You could also have a generator that refuses to yield:

```
def noyield():
    while True:
        pass
    yield 1  # Not happening.
```

Comment: This is such a quick and perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 issues here:

```
number = yield number
```

will set `number` to `None` (as you do not `send` anything to the generator).

the second issue is: your generator never terminates. if you generate a list from that python probably run into a memory overflow.

this is what you could do:

```
import math

def get_primes(start, stop):
    n = start
    while True:
        if n >= stop:
            raise StopIteration
        if is_prime(n):
            yield n
        n += 1

def is_prime(number):
    # no changes here

generator = get_primes(5, 15)
print list(generator)  # [5, 7, 11, 13]
```

any generator that does not raise an exception other than `StopIteration` and terminates can be converted to a list.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
number += 1
```

to

```
number = number + 1 if (number is not None) else 1
```

In that way you would only update number if something sent to it and avoid exception mentioned above. **But you would override number if you won't sent value to generator.**

But two issues described by **@hiro protagonist** still exist!