# Python generator yield behaviour

Tags: python, generator, yield

So I have [the following generator function](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/generator/send.html):

```
def gen(n=5):
    for i in range(n):
        n = yield n

for i in gen(3):
    print(i)
```

### The result:

```
3
None
None
```

---

I understand the first result of yield is 3. Because I assigned 3 to function argument `n`. But **where are the `None` in the second and third yield coming from?** Is it because in the for-loop, `yield n` returns `None` and this `None` is assigned to `n` in this line: `n = yield n`?

Comment: What have you gathered from the generator and `yield` statement documentation?

Comment: Yes, you have provided your explanation.

Comment: you should call gen() from INSIDE the loop

Comment: @Roland And why would you want to do *that*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in [the documentation of yield expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions), especially this part:

> The value of the yield expression after resuming depends on the method
> which resumed the execution. If **next**() is used (typically via
> either a for or the next() builtin) then the result is None.
> Otherwise, if send() is used, then the result will be the value passed
> in to that method.

As you use a `for` loop, `n` just gets `None` as a value when resuming after the first yield. So, from now on, `n` is `None`, and this is what will be yielded the last two times.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. It's interesting `send()` is designed to change the result value of the yield expression. I thought `send()` was to insert a new value in the sequence being yielded.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you answered your own question:

> because in the for-loop, yield n returns None and None is assigned to n in this line: n = yield n

You can read more at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10695490/10155119).